# Is there any advantage in getting a nosejob?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

None of the rhinoplasty options seem to visually change anything, with the sole exception being the insanely expensive 'The Hasselhoff'. I know this is a joke about the character designs of South Park, and was featured in an episode if memory serves, but is there any benefit in game? A person who will only friend you if you've got The Hasselhoff or something?

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrat... oh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an achievement for beating the game while rocking the **The Hoff** Nose Job, and unlike the other options, it also provides some pretty significant visual customization. At a minimum, it's worth trying it and reloading a save for a laugh.

Beyond that, characters around you will remark on your 'new' face as you wander around South Park. Particularly if you're a Jew.